# Delete nested comments with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm having some issues deleting my comments with Ajax. I think I'm close but not sure and would like some advice. Still getting used to jquery and such. I can remove the comment via ajax but not actually delete the record itself so maybe its a simple syntax issue.

destroy.js.erb

```
$('#remove_comment').remove();
```

I think I need to tag this with the comment ID but I'm having issues being as the comments are nested under the Pit model.

_comment.html.erb

```
<div class = "well", id = "remove_comment">
    <p>
      <%= comment.body %>
    <p>posted by: <%= comment.user.name %></p>
    <div class = "response">
       <p class = "like-response">Was this response persuading to you?</p>
       <%= link_to "Yes", pit_comment_like_path(@pit, comment), method: :put %>
       <%= link_to "No", pit_comment_dislike_path(@pit, comment), method: :put %>
    </div>

    <div class = "response-convince">
      <p class = "dislike-comment">
        <%= comment.get_dislikes.size %> users found this response unpersuasive
      </p>
       <p class = "like-comment">
        <%= comment.get_likes.size %> users found this response persuasive</p>
      </p>
    </div>
    <p>


    <%if comment.user == current_user %>

     <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [@pit, comment],
                 method: :delete,
                 data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true, class: "btn btn-default" %>
    </p>
  <% end %>  
</div>
```

Comments Controller

```
def destroy
  @pit = Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
  @comment = @pit.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to pit_path(@pit)}
        format.js {}
    end
```

Logs seem to be working properly

```
Started DELETE "/pits/398/comments/63" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-11 12:31:08 -0500
Processing by CommentsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"pit_id"=>"398", "id"=>"63"}
  Pit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "pits".* FROM "pits"  WHERE "pits"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 398]]
  Comment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."pit_id" = ? AND "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["pit_id", 398], ["id", 63]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ActsAsVotable::Vote Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "votes".* FROM "votes"  WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = ? AND "votes"."votable_type" = ?  [["votable_id", 63], ["votable_type", "Comment"]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ?  [["id", 63]]
   (3.0ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered comments/destroy.js.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 3.9ms | ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)
```

This is the associated markup I have in pits/show.html.erb

```
    <h3>Responses</h3>
  <div id = "comment_body">
    <%= render @pit.comments %>
  </div>
    <%= render partial: "comments/form" %>
```

pit.rb

```
class Pit < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :topic, :author, :summary, presence: true
  acts_as_votable
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :pit
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Everything inserts correctly with my create.js.erb. I just need to remove it and I think I need to pass in the comment ID or something to that effect. Any advice here would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `remove()` simply takes an element out of the DOM, you would need to send data to server with ajax to remove from db. Seem to be missing ajax code here

Comment: K. Thats what I was sort of wondering. I'm just having issues doing that. I've tried looking up a few things but it seems everything I find isn't dealing with nested comments. I watched Ryan Bates railscast on it and he used an "edit" method to delete the record. That didn't work for me or at least not how I implemented it.

Comment: can use a data attribite on element like your button to store an db ID, then send that to server as part of click handler. Also get impression you may be repeating element ID's which by definition must be unique

Comment: I guess your comment is being deleted properly, as you displayed in the logs? What's the issue you see? `$('#remove_comment').remove();` will remove all the comments actually than the one you want to remove from the page via jQuery.

Comment: I must specify. This $('#remove_comment').remove(); removes the element but does actually delete anything. Everything else I've tried with regards to the destroy.js.erb file removes the comment from the DB but does nothing to the DOM. I specifically added #remove_comment id to my well in order to test and remove the element from the page.

Comment: My create.js.erb looks as such - $('#comment_body').append("<%= j(render 'comment', comment: @comment, pit: @ pit ) %>");

I need the equivalent to delete. I thought it would be easy. Something like $('#remove_comment').remove("<%= j(render 'comment', comment: @ comment, pit: @ pit ) %>"); ? But it doesn't remove anything. It does however successfully delete the comment itself upon refresh

Comment: @MarkHustad Try the answer I've posted. I think it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the comment is being DELETED as logs shows the query:

```
SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ?  [["id", 63]]
```

I guess your jQuery doesn't remove the appropriate comment after the callback. You can try changing view code of _comment.html.erb:

```
<div class = "well", id = "remove_comment_<%= comment.id %>">
    <p>
      <%= comment.body %>
```

And then your destroy.js.erb:

```
$("#remove_comment_<%= @comment.id %>").remove(); // Since @comment will be available in the variable here!
```

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for Surya. Very much appreciated. That makes sense too because the id wasn't available to remove until after someone made a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

create a link_to with a data-id attribute, when clicked use jquery to make a GET request to your controller.

First, create a route for the delete action in your config/routes.rb:

```
get 'delete_comment' => 'comments#delete_comment'
```

Next, add a method to your controller (assumably CommentsController):

```
def delete_comment
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy
end
```

Now, set up a link in your view:

```
= link_to "Remove Comment", "#", :class => "remove_comment", :'data-id' => @comment.id
```

Now set up the jquery GET request to fire when you click on the link:

```
$(".remove_comment").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $.get("/delete_comment", {id: $(this).attr("data-id") } );
});
```

In this example, you would need to rename your delete.js.erb file to delete_comment.js.erb

Comment: I'll see what I can do here and let you know. Thanks for the suggestion